# JavaScript, how to GET the value/content/bits of element dropped?

Tags: javascript

I need send file, and I want drag/drop
without use JQUERY
then I try get the BITS of file with:

```
<form action="https://cocacola.tld/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<input type="file" name="bitsfile" />

<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" ondrop="document.forms.bitsfile.value = BITS_from_this_DROPPED_element;">drag file here</div>

<hr /><input type="submit" />
</form>
```

but of course "BITS_from_this_DROPPED_element" not work.

how I can get the value "binary" or bits of element dropped?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
<form action="https://cocacola.tld/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="bitsfile" id="bitsfile" />
    
    <div style="min-height: 100px;" id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" ondragenter="document.getElementById('bitsfile').value = ''; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();" ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();" ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); dodrop(event);" >drag file here</div>
    
    <hr /><input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function dodrop(event)
    {
        var dt = event.dataTransfer;
        var files = dt.files;

        var count = files.length;
        var temp = "File Count: " + count + "\n";
        var sumBits = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            temp += " File " + i + ":\n(" + (typeof files[i]) + ") : <" + files[i] + " > " +
                files[i].name + " " + files[i].size + "\n";
            sumBits+= files[i].size;
        }
        document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText = temp;
        document.getElementById('bitsfile').value = sumBits;
    }

</script>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files

Comment: thanks @MinhTD, your form not ADD the file, and (when is image, not SHOW image) before of send form. The target is get the file (bits), not te size of file.

Answer (score 0):

the "big trick" is:

```
FileReader()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

now, if you want **preview** images:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL